# find all files owned by a user with desired extension in perl

Tags: perl, unix

My requirement is to process all the files of .log type owned by the execution user.
the below code is not working.
Thanks in advance...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$cmn_dir="/tmp";
my $USER = $ENV{'LOGNAME'};
print "user:$USER\n";
@ifile_log="find $cmn_dir -user $USER -type f -name \"*.log\"";
foreach $file(@ifile_log)
{
        print "file:$file\n";
}
```

Comment: What part doesn't work?  It seems short enough that you can error check line by line.

Comment: Hint: There's something called `find2perl` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually executing the Unix "find" command, you are just storing it in a string variable.

You need to either put it in backticks

```
`find ...`;
```

or in qx() like this

```
qx(find ...);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here some links to help you:

1. [Perl glob function to list all *.log files](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)
2. [Perl stat function
   to get file owner id](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html)
3. [Perl variables tutorial to find current
   user id](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)